# Flex 3 Multicolored Text in DataGrid Cell

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, textcolor

I am having an issue with styling individual cells in a DataGrid.  I want to go through the text in a DataGrid cell and only color a specific portion of the text.

When a User uses a search filter, we want to color and bold the text in the cell that matches the search phrase.  For example, the User filters a column of job titles with the search phrase "Adjust" and one of the cell values is "Claim Adjusters", we want "Claim " and "ers" at the end to be black font color and the "Adjust" to be another color (let's say red).

I noticed that if the String passed to the DataGrid was of the form:

value.substring(0,start) + "(b)" + value.substring(start,finish) + "(/b)" + value.substring(finish);

With "<>" rather than "()", the text between the bold tags gets displayed with a bold font, but it does not work with (font color=\"red\") ... (/font).
Any suggestions on how I can get the search text to color here as well as bold?

Answer (score 1):

[Only hexadecimal color (#FFFFFF) values are supported.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText)

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative with lots of flexibility is to make your itemRendrer support html formatting:

```
public class HtmlItemRenderer extends DataGridItemRenderer {
    override public function validateProperties():void {
        super.validateProperties();
        if (text.indexOf('<') > -1) {
            htmlText = text;
        }
    }
}
```

The conditional doesn't need to be very strict, it will still save some cycles for most cells that contain no markup.